# Rails install says "libxml2" library is missing, even though "brew install" tells me its there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, libxml2, osx-yosemite

I”m trying to install Rails on my Mac Yosemite system.  When I initially tried

```
sudo brew rails install
```

I got complaints about the “libxml2” library being missing.  So I installed that using

```
brew install libxml2
```

But running the above command to install rails still fails complaining about libxml2 not being installed.  What to do?  Below is the complete output from the command line.  You can see that when I try and install libxml2 again, it tells me it is already installed.

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro-2:workspace davea$ brew install libxml2
Warning: libxml2-2.9.3 already installed
Daves-MacBook-Pro-2:workspace davea$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.0.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch
    - 0003-Stop-parsing-on-entities-boundaries-errors.patch
    - 0004-Cleanup-conditional-section-error-handling.patch
    - 0005-CVE-2015-1819-Enforce-the-reader-to-run-in-constant-.patch
    - 0006-Another-variation-of-overflow-in-Conditional-section.patch
    - 0007-Fix-an-error-in-previous-Conditional-section-patch.patch
    - 0008-CVE-2015-8035-Fix-XZ-compression-support-loop.patch
    - 0009-Updated-config.guess.patch
    - 0010-Fix-parsering-short-unclosed-comment-uninitialized-access.patch
    - 0011-Avoid-extra-processing-of-MarkupDecl-when-EOF.patch
    - 0012-Avoid-processing-entities-after-encoding-conversion-.patch
    - 0013-CVE-2015-7497-Avoid-an-heap-buffer-overflow-in-xmlDi.patch
    - 0014-CVE-2015-5312-Another-entity-expansion-issue.patch
    - 0015-Add-xmlHaltParser-to-stop-the-parser.patch
    - 0016-Detect-incoherency-on-GROW.patch
    - 0017-CVE-2015-7500-Fix-memory-access-error-due-to-incorre.patch
    - 0018-CVE-2015-8242-Buffer-overead-with-HTML-parser-in-pus.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0003-Stop-parsing-on-entities-boundaries-errors.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0004-Cleanup-conditional-section-error-handling.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0005-CVE-2015-1819-Enforce-the-reader-to-run-in-constant-.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0006-Another-variation-of-overflow-in-Conditional-section.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0007-Fix-an-error-in-previous-Conditional-section-patch.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0008-CVE-2015-8035-Fix-XZ-compression-support-loop.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0009-Updated-config.guess.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0010-Fix-parsering-short-unclosed-comment-uninitialized-access.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0011-Avoid-extra-processing-of-MarkupDecl-when-EOF.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0012-Avoid-processing-entities-after-encoding-conversion-.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0013-CVE-2015-7497-Avoid-an-heap-buffer-overflow-in-xmlDi.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0014-CVE-2015-5312-Another-entity-expansion-issue.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0015-Add-xmlHaltParser-to-stop-the-parser.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0016-Detect-incoherency-on-GROW.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0017-CVE-2015-7500-Fix-memory-access-error-due-to-incorre.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxml2/0018-CVE-2015-8242-Buffer-overead-with-HTML-parser-in-pus.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14/libxml2/2.9.2)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
    - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
    - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
    - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
    - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
    - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
    - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
    - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
    - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
    - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
    - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
    - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch
    - 0016-Fix-for-type-confusion-in-preprocessing-attributes.patch
    - 0017-Updated-config.guess.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0016-Fix-for-type-confusion-in-preprocessing-attributes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/patches/libxslt/0017-Updated-config.guess.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.28 (from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14/libxslt/1.1.28)...
checking for main() in -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -llibxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  Please locate mkmf.log to investigate how it is failing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml2lib
    --without-libxml2lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Also, there is no file on my system “mkmf.log ”, as the error message suggests.

Comment: did you figure this out. i had the same issue. very annoying